# how to break out servo.write(angle) after it reach the angle?

Tags: servo, code-review, analogwrite

I used a servo as a grabber so I don't know the angle I need specifically.I need it to break the `serve.write(angle)` when the grabber holds something.
I used a simple code

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo; 
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9); 
}
void loop() {
  myservo.write(100);                  
  delay(500);
  myservo.write(50);                  
  delay(500);                           
}
```

when it holds anything it deos not return to the small angle until I remove the obstacle from its way.

Answer (score 1):

You change the angle in small increments until the sensor triggers:

```
bool closing = false;
bool openeing = false;
int angle;

void loop(){

    //read touchSensor

    if(sensorHit){
        closing  = false;
    }
    if(closing){
        if(angle <= minAngle) closing = false;
        angle -= 1;
        myservo.write(angle);

    }

    if(opening){
        if(angle >= maxAngle) opening = false;
        angle += 1;
        myservo.write(angle);

    }

}
```

The to start moving the grasper you set `opening` or `closing` to true. You can also add some trigger logic in the places where they get set back to false for the next movement if applicable.

Comment: when I control it manually by joystick, if I hold press a little I can not reverse the angle. I don't use touchSensor.